# what are the basis on which I should define resources tag in webapi.xml

Tags: magento2, api

what are the basis on which I should define resources tag in webapi.xml.
for example if I build an api to return product information who can access it.
I've searched for that but all I found is what is acl.xml file is used for

Answer (score 1):

Valid values are self, anonymous, or a Magento resource, such as Magento_Customer::group.

- anonymous => everyone can use the API
- self => online logged-in customers can use the API
- Magento resource, such as Magento_Customer::group => only admin users with the specified resource can access the API

An API should be as restrictive as possible to prevent unauthorized uses.

Comment: So, If I'm creating an API I should create an acl.xml file for it, right?

Comment: @YomnaMansour it depends. you only need an acl.xml if you're defining new resources. give this a read to understand ACL https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_access_control_list_rules/